# How do I make three range slider values open a specific link

Tags: javascript, html

I have three range sliders and one button. Depending on the values of all three sliders I need the button to open a link.

This is where I am stuck, I must be missing some piece of JS logic or getting syntax wrong:

```
<div>
  <p>Search by three values:</p>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" id="myRange1">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" id="myRange2">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" id="myRange3">

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myRange1").value
  var y = document.getElementById("myRange2").value
  var z = document.getElementById("myRange3").value

  if (myRange1 === "1" && myRange2 === "1" && myRange3 === "1") {
    window.location.assign("https://www.google.com")
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pcoledesign/jmc1nzv4/4/

Comment: Your `var`iables are called `x`, `y`, and `z`, so those are the ones you should use for comparison. Side remark: numerical input types, such as the range control you have, offer a `valueAsNumber` field too (producing an actual number instead of the string what `value` contains).

Answer (score 0):

You should try checking for equality against vars `x`, `y` and `z`

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myRange1").value
  var y = document.getElementById("myRange2").value
  var z = document.getElementById("myRange3").value

  if (x === "1" && y === "1" && z === "1") {
    window.location.assign("https://www.google.com")
  }
}
```

Hint: Use `console.log()` to see what the values of `myRange1` and `x` are and why your equality check might be failing.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myRange1").value
var y = document.getElementById("myRange2").value
var z = document.getElementById("myRange3").value

console.log('myRange1: ', myRange1)
console.log('x: ', x)
console.log('x === myRange1: ', x === myRange1)
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Search by three values:</p>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" id="myRange1">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" id="myRange2">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" id="myRange3">
</div>
```

[A note for those wondering why these undeclared variables don't cause a ReferenceError.](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you confused the id with the variable names you assigned the values to. What you meant was:

`(x === "1" && y === "1" && z === "1")`

Answer (score 0):

You stored the values of inputs in the variables x, y and z.
So the expression should be:

```
if(x === "1" && y ==="1" && z==="1"){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are `x`, `y` and `z`, not `myRange1`, `myRange2` or `myRange3`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myRange1").value
  var y = document.getElementById("myRange2").value
  var z = document.getElementById("myRange3").value

  if (x === "1" && y === "1" && z === "1") {
    window.location.assign("https://www.google.com")
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you suggest `==`?

Comment: @tevemadar: it seems I made a mistake when correcting OP's fiddle. When I did it, only `==` worked and I didn't stop to investigate why (I assumed that range sliders were inherently ints, not strings). Looking at it now, `===` does in fact work; so I'm removing that part from my answer. I don't know what I did to not make it work before.